# filedialog doesn't show up the window on top

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, spyder

I am trying to get a file name from a GUI using Tkinter. Below is the code and I am using Spyder/Anaconda on windows. The dialog doesn't show up in the taskbar and it is visible only when I minimize the spyder window. Any way to solve this issue?

```
import tkinter, tkinter.filedialog
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_path = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root,title='Pick a file')
```

Comment: Works just fine in Python 3.6.5 under Windows 10. Dialog does not show up in the taskbar when root is withdrawn but then again the dialog does not show up in the taskbar when root is visible. Only root does. Can the problem be with Spyder/Anaconda?

Comment: when I remove `root.withdraw`, the root window appears; when I click on it to give it focus, the filedialog appears.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root)
root.destroy()
```

This works.